# How to toggle text mode for equation editor instead of manually editing it each time?

Tags: microsoft-word, equation-editor

I'm trying to have equations (with math symbols, not just regular text) be in text mode for a document I'm working on, but to do that one has to manually select the equation and turn on text mode. Is there a faster way to do this? A way to have all equations be automatically formatted in text mode or a shortcut maybe?

For reference, here is what I'm trying to replicate.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by text mode? How exactly do you turn it on?

Comment: Are you just trying to replicate that equation including the non-italic letters? Can we ignore the two black marks under your equation?

Comment: Sorry for the late response! I figured out how to do it. Turns out you can just use MathType and configure it to give non-italic symbols in equations